# Circuit type that confuses me

Tags: circuit-analysis

Can someone help me with this sort of circuits?

[image]

I don't see how it works because the circuit isn't closed like this type:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This circuit is equivalent to the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB6Ccr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The ground symbol (the three lines that you see twice at the bottom of your schematic) indicates two things:

1. this is connected to every other ground symbol in the circuit, and
2. this is what we're calling zero volts.

The arrows pointing up with a number of volts written by them indicate two things:

1. this is connected to every other arrow with the same voltage in the circuit, and
2. There's a voltage source of x volts between here and ground.

The reason circuits are drawn like this is that, for complex circuits, it would get very confusing very quickly if you had to draw lines back to the voltage source for every single thing that was connected to ground. Imagine doing that for a PC motherboard's schematic!

Comment: Thanks. Is there any name for these circuits so I can google it for more?

Comment: @derva_, it's not a special kind of circuit. It's just a simpler way of drawing a schematic.

Answer (score 3):

The circuits are closed through the power supplies which are omitted for clarity but shown via the +6 V and +5 V labels.

- Label your resistors R1 to R4 so we can discuss them.
- Label the two nodes at each end of the diode so we can discuss them.
- Figure out what the voltages at those nodes would be if the diode was not there.
- Now add in the diode. Is it forward biased or reverse biased. What will happen in each case?
- If it's forward biased are you to assume an ideal diode (no voltage drop) or a practical silicon diode (V<sub>f</sub> = 0.7 V?

Can you work it out from there?

Update your question with your calculations. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar and you can use that to create a new schematic and show the stages of your work. Double-click to edit a component's properties. 'R' to rotate.

Comment: Or (more unlikely) a practical diode taking reverse leakage into account.